# How to visualize a time series in react with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I went through different tutorials on how to show a simple time series on React. Most of them don't use hook, so I tried to adapt the code. I got stuck when tried to retrieve data with Axios from an open API. The error I got are `ERROR in ./src/App.js Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js)` and `ERROR in src/App.js Line 27:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," (27:0)`

I am encountered these errors even before to try to show something. It seems something linked with the axios.get or there is something wrong with my useEffect hook.
Could you please help me with this?
Many thanks

```
import React , { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const  App =()=> {
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let x = [];
    let y = [];
        
    axios.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rc75-m7u3.json').then(response=>{
      console.log('response',response)
      response.map(each => {
      x.push(each.date_of_interest)
      y.push(each.case_count)
   
      .catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
        }, [])
 
     
  
    return (
      <div>Hello </div>
    )}

export default App;
```

Comment: In Axios.get function some paracentesis and curly braces are missing and the first bug is related to npm packages. Did you install react? İf you are, try delete node_modules and write nmp install to terminal

Answer (score 0):

loop on response.data:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    let x = [];
    let y = [];

    axios
      .get("https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rc75-m7u3.json")
      .then((response) => {
        response.data.forEach((each) => {
          x.push(each.date_of_interest);
          y.push(each.case_count);
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  return <div>Hello </div>;
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/axios-0jobj)

Comment: Many thanks! So If I understand correctly it has been a problem of "reading" the json correctly. I iterated the wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues here:

1. There are typos in your code - you're missing a closing `});` after pushing your data
2. You need to use an additional 'state' hook in order to access your data outside the effect function.
3. You need to parse your response as json, after fetching it.
4. You need to iterate over the data inside the render function in order to print it:

```js
import React , { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';

const  App =()=> {
  const [xCoords, setXCoord] = useState([]);
  const [yCoords, setYCoord] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('https://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/rc75-m7u3.json')
      .then(response=> response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setXCoords(data.date_of_interest);
        setYCoords(data.case_count);
      }).catch((error) => {console.log(error)})
  }, [])
 
     
  
    return (
      <div>Hello </div>
      <pre>
         { xCoords.map(x => <span>{x}</span>) }
      </pre>
    )}

export default App;
```

Comment: Many Thanks. I went through it and I think that there is a missing 's' in setXCoord and setYCoord. Beside that I can see that you put the map outside the useEffect . If I understand correctly you are creating the array of x values outside the useEffect. So if I want to plot them using a library like apexchart I have to do the same for the y variables and then plot it.

Comment: Correct.
I fixed the typo.
Good luck!